# opening a Modal - how to include a querystring value?

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have a link that opens a Modal window in Bootstrap 3:

```
<a href="#enlargeModal">Link Text</a>
```

Is it possible to carry over a querystring value in that link, kinda like this (which I've tried but it causes the Modal to stop working):

```
<a href="#enlargeModal?id=1">Link Text</a>
```

I have a series of thumbnail images that I'd like people to be able to expand by clicking on a link, have it open a Modal window with the larger version of the image on display (both the thumbnail and the large scale image have the same file name).

Would appreciate your advice. Maybe it would just be easier to use something like Lightbox?

Thank you.
NJ

Comment: a jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: I don't know how to do a jsfiddle, sorry.